# How to set json maxlength in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc, serialization, deserialization

I want to set Json maxlength during serialization in Javascript as I am creating Obj in Js file itself. From there I am sending to a controller Action (MVC).

Is there a way to set maxLength in Javascript?

Comment: The `maxlength` is an integer property that `defaults between 102400-2097152` but you can set up to `50000000`. `"Is there a way to set maxLength in Javascript?"`- yes you can like this `<jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"/>` You have a look [official document  here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.configuration.scriptingjsonserializationsection.maxjsonlength?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_Configuration_ScriptingJsonSerializationSection_MaxJsonLength)

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron We can set inside controller using the method you mentioned above. I want to do in JavaScript and then send the serialized Obj to Action of Controller. I am Getting maxlength Exceeded Error during serialization of Obj (in JS file)

Comment: `JavaScript` doesn't allow to set upper limit this way, I think you have to set that on backend. Just pass the object as `JSON.stringify` then set the limit on backend this is the way for you.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron In JSON.stringify, maxLength is exceeded so, I am getting a error on that line only.

Comment: Yes so you have left one way, update the configuration in suggested way as we cannnot set maxlength in client side.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.